# Calculus simple stuff

Tags: calculus

Background: I did study mathematics in my high school, but never did so seriously. However, I have again got up interest in learning some topics (calculus to start with).

I started with Silvanus Thompson online book "Calculus Made Easy" and I have a doubt (may be very naive) on this part:

The volume of a cylinder of radius $r$ and height $h$ is given by
the formula $V = πr^{2}h$. Find the rate of variation of volume with the
radius when $r=5.5in$ and $h=20in$. If $r=h$, find the dimensions
of the cylinder so that a change of $1in$ in radius causes a change of
$400in^3$ in the volume.

Now, the rate of change ${dv\over dr}$ is $690.8$ which is okay, and the difference of volume at radius $5$ and $6$ is same. This hold true for rate of change at radius $2.5(v(3)-v(2) = {dv\over dr}$ at radius $2.5, 3.5 , 4.5,etc.$ with height as $20in$.

Doubt: why only the rate of change at radius $5.5$ matches with the change in volume at radius $5$ and $6$? Is there some obvious property or some basic which I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second degree polynomials 
$$f(t)=At^2+Bt+C$$
(and no other functions) have the property that
$$f(b)-f(a)=\>f'\left({a+b\over2}\right)\>(b-a)$$
for arbitrary $a$, $b\in{\mathbb R}$.

Comment: yes this explains my math. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This is true in general for this specific example. Using derivative, the rate of change at $r$ is
$$\frac{dV}{dr}=2\pi rh$$
The change of volume between $r-\frac{1}{2}$ and $r+\frac{1}{2}$ is
$$\pi \left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 h-\pi \left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 h\\
=\pi h \left(r^2+r+\frac{1}{4}-\left(r^2-r+\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\\
=2\pi r h$$

Does that answer your question?